# Continuously differentiable positive definite function

Tags: derivatives, positive-definite

Suppose there is a continuously differentiable multivariable scalar function $f$ such that

for
$\forall {\bf{p}} \in {R^n}$

$f\left( {{\bf{p}},{\bf{q}}} \right) > 0$
$\forall {\bf{q}} \in {R^n} - \left\{ 0 \right\}$

$f\left( {{\bf{p}},{\bf{q}}} \right)=0$
if
$\bf{q}=\bf{0}$

Namely, $f$ is positive definite with respect to $\bf{q}$.

What kind of sufficient or N-S condition is needed to say that

$\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial {\bf{q}}}}{\bf{q}} > 0$
$\forall {\bf{p}} \in {R^n}$
$\forall {\bf{q}} \in {R^n} - \left\{ 0 \right\}$

?
I think
$\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial {\bf{q}}}} \ne {\bf{0}}$
is only a condition needed. But I am not sure.

You can just ignore $\bf{p}$ in the statement. That is, $f=f\left(\bf{q}\right)$.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How are you defining $C$?

Comment: @NicholasStull Oops I made a mistake. $C \leftarrow f$ in this case.

Comment: If $f$ is convex with respect to $\bf{q}$, it is sufficient to show that$\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial {\bf{q}}}}{\bf{q}}>0$ on a domain.